# dircolors: rules for _ext (rather than .ext)

Tags: ls, colors

In UNIX, many file extensions do not contain the dot in front, as in `bashrc` rather than `bash.rc` or `ssh_config` rather than `ssh.config`

I would like to add dircolor rules for `_config` as well. However, when I add the line:

```
_config 01;31
```

I get an error: `` dircolors: `/etc/dircolors':126: unrecognized keyword _config ``

Is it possible to add extensions `_ext` to dircolors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `*_config 01;31`.

From `man 5 dir_colors`:

```
*extension color-sequence
    Specifies the color used for any file that ends in extension.

.extension color-sequence
    Same as *.extension. Specifies the color used for any file that ends
    in .extension. Note that the period is included in the extension, which
    makes it impossible to specify an extension not starting with a period,
    such as ~ for emacs backup files. This form should be considered obsolete.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I don't see any mention of regular expressions or case sensitivity in the `man` page. Is it possible to use regex ? And do I need to specify all possible permutations of lower upper case `.mp3, .MP3, .Mp3, ...`, or is there one expression that will match all?

Comment: Unforunately it's case sensitive and you can't use regexes. You have to list out all the possible permutations. I checked the source for `ls` just to make sure there aren't any undocumented features to workaround this, and there aren't. It's just a regular string comparison against the file extension.

Comment: No, there are no undocumented features. BUT someone has already tried hard to work on this issue, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2012-10/msg00057.html . Unfortunately the author of the patch decided to discard the patch shortly after for various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

As @Matt has corrected me, this is possible using `dir_colors`. To do this you need to add a line similar to this in one of a few locations.

- /etc/DIR_COLORS
- $HOME/.dircolors

*excerpt from man page*

```
found in a system default shell initialization file, like /etc/profile or 
/etc/csh.cshrc.  (See  also  dircolors(1).)   Usually, the file used here is 
/etc/DIR_COLORS and can be overridden by a .dir_colors file in one's home 
directory.
```

These files are typically sourced from these files that are patched into your `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.bash_profile`, assuming you're using Bash as your shell.

```
$ ls -l /etc/profile.d/|grep colorls
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1133 Nov  3  2010 colorls.csh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1143 Nov  3  2010 colorls.sh
```

If you add your line to say your copy of `$HOME/.dircolors`:

```
_config 01;31
```

You can then update your environment using this command:

```
$ source /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
```

You can then confirm that your environment now includes the change:

```
$ env|grep -o '*_config=01;31'
*_config=01;31
```

Finally you can test to see if your change is working:

```
$ touch afile_config
ls -l afile_config
```

[image: ss of ls output]